# Filter bitbucket pull requests based on start and end date

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am fetching *pull requests* for a particular *repository* using Bitbucket REST API version 2.0.

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/search?q=tag:pullrequests

Below REST API works and list all the pull requests.

`/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/pullrequests`

Now I want to apply filters on above API eg

1. Fetch all pull request by passing start and end date
2. Count all approved/declined pull requests.

Comment: as of 2023, the pull-requests api is ordered by latest date.